# show duplicates from list in counting operation python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

i have `corpus_text` with string of text, then i'm convert this to list with split on words

i need to count all of words, but my algorithm counting only unique

```
corpus_test = 'cat dog tiger tiger tiger cat dog lion'
corpus_test = [[word.lower() for word in corpus_test.split()]]
word_counts = defaultdict(int)
for rowt in corpus_test:
    for wordt in rowt:
        word_counts[wordt] += 1

        v_count = len(word_counts.keys())

        words_list = list(word_counts.keys())

        word_index = dict((word, i) for i, word in enumerate(words_list))

        index_word = dict((i, word) for i, word in enumerate(words_list))
```

and i want show you outputs from this algorithm

```
v_count
#4

words_list
#['cat', 'dog', 'tiger', 'lion']

word_counts
#defaultdict(int, {'cat': 2, 'dog': 2, 'tiger': 3, 'lion': 1})

word_index
#{'cat': 0, 'dog': 1, 'tiger': 2, 'lion': 3}

index_word
#{0: 'cat', 1: 'dog', 2: 'tiger', 3: 'lion'}
```

i need to have:

```
index_word
#{0: 'cat', 1: 'dog', 2: 'tiger', 3: 'tiger', 4: 'tiger', 5: 'cat', 6: 'dog', 7:'lion'}
```

and

```
v_count
#8
```

Comment: You should not. You can only have one word occuring 10 times, if two words occure 10 times only one shows up. dictionary keys are unique

Comment: looks like you're generating your word_counts dict properly. Have you tried printing word_counts?
If you need this reversed output for an answer this may work:
`for word, count in word_counts: print(f"{count}: '{word}'")`

Comment: @Ch3steR Misread the question, tks.

Comment: @PedroLobito Not a problem. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with the existing algorithm, you can try this.

```
index_word = dict((i, word) for i, word in enumerate(rowt)) 
v_count = len(index_word)
```

Comment: The generator expression is redundant: `dict(enumerate(rowt))`

Answer (score 4):

If you want a map of indices to words, just... do that?

```py
index_word = dict(enumerate(word.lower() for word in corpus_test.split()))
```

Or you have to store lists / sets of indices in your `word_index`, a dict is not a multimap, it maps a single key to a single value (though either can be composite).

Also `word_counts` could be a `collection.Counter`, it has useful features (like topN, or the ability to replicate / unfold items by their count).

Comment: your first `code` line is can't be launch with error `'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: What's the reason behind making `word.lower()`.Nice answer. +1

Comment: @germanjke Use `corpus_test = 'cat dog tiger tiger tiger cat dog lion'`. It's bad practice to use the same name for different things like in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate` for `index_list`

```
corpus_test = 'cat dog tiger tiger tiger cat dog lion'
index_list=dict(enumerate(corpus_test.split()))
#{0: 'cat', 1: 'dog', 2: 'tiger', 3: 'tiger', 4: 'tiger', 5: 'cat', 6: 'dog', 7:'lion'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
corpus_test = 'cat dog tiger tiger tiger cat dog lion'
words=dict(enumerate([w.lower() for w in corpus_test.split()]))
print(words)
print(len(words))
# {0: 'cat', 1: 'dog', 2: 'tiger', 3: 'tiger', 4: 'tiger', 5: 'cat', 6: 'dog', 7: 'lion'}
# 8
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/865837c6ed)

Comment: `enumerate` takes generators also...doing `dict(enumerate(w.lower() for w in corpus_test.split()))` improves the answer avoiding building a list. Nice answer though. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve using `itertools count()` method.

```
from itertools import count

corpus_test = 'cat dog tiger tiger tiger cat dog lion'
index_list = dict(zip(count(), corpus_test.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using basic python,
it can be done as:

```
corpus_text = 'cat dog tiger tiger tiger cat dog lion'
split_text = corpus_text.split()

my_dict = {i:split_text[i] for i in range(len(split_text))}

v_count = len(my_dict.keys())

print(f"""index_word
{my_dict}

v_count
{v_count}""" )
```

which gives

```
index_word
{0: 'cat', 1: 'dog', 2: 'tiger', 3: 'tiger', 4: 'tiger', 5: 'cat', 6: 'dog', 7: 'lion'}

v_count
8
```